# How to export a function using React and Babel?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, babeljs

Trying to display the Buho function I have on component.js. It won't, and when using import Buho from './component.js' the local functions also don't display.
I have the local file addition.html to display the website.

I tried adding on addition.html

Nothing different.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>    

    <title>Adition</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="owlButton">Owl</div>
    <div id="catButton">Cat</div>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <div id="component">C</div>
    
    <script type="text/babel" src="adition.js" >
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

adition.js

```
    
    import Buho from './component.js'

    const owl = {
    title: 'Excellent Owl',
    src: 'https://content.codecademy.com/courses/React/react_photo-owl.jpg'
    };

    const cat = {
    title: 'Excellent Cat',
    src: 'https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/F766A67E-A8AA-4C90-A929C9AC67075D4B_source.jpg?w=590&h=800&8027B6C0-FF94-49F8-B44F07788CEF1BE1'
    };


    function Owl(){
        return (
      <div>
        <h1>{owl.title}</h1>
        <h1><img src={owl.src} alt={owl.title}/></h1>
      </div>
    );
    }

    function Cat(){
        return (
      <div>
        <h1>{cat.title}</h1>
        <h1><img src={cat.src} alt={cat.title}/></h1>
      </div>
        );
    }

    document.querySelector('#owlButton').addEventListener("click", function(){
        ReactDOM.render(<Owl />, document.querySelector('#content'))
    });

    document.querySelector('#catButton').addEventListener("click", function(){
        ReactDOM.render(<Cat />, document.querySelector('#content'))
    });
    
    ReactDOM.render(<Buho />, document.querySelector('#component'))
```

components.js

```
import React from 'react';

function Buho(){
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>owl.título</h1>
        <h1>owl.imagen</h1>
      </div>
    );
}

export default Buho;
```

They are just my first exercises. I am trying to understand how this works.